# Windows checksums?

Tags: windows, checksum

I am looking for a official source for windows checksums (in my special case windows xp). Normally I use the "Microsoft Benefit Portal" for that, but seems like it's gone, at least I can't find it anymore using google ): Anyone knows where to find the checksums on the microsoft website? Thanks :-)

Comment: Have you asked Microsoft about this?

Answer (score 2):

MSDN Subscriber Downloads contains the SHA1 checksums for all of the official Microsoft ISOs.  If you don't have access to MSDN, tell me exactly what version/edition of Windows XP you want and I can tell you the checksum. For example:
[image]

Comment: hmm benefit portal was public, that sucks ;-) but thanks for your reply - i am interested in xp sp3 vl x86 english, but the normal one, not the "n" one - thanks :-)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I don't know of a public place, only MSDN for subscribers. :\  But here you go: 

Windows XP Professional with Service Pack 3 (x86) - CD VL (English)
ISO|English|Release Date: 5/2/2008

589 MB
File Name: en_windows_xp_professional_with_service_pack_3_x86_cd_vl_x14-73974.iso
Languages: English
SHA1: 66ac289ae27724c5ae17139227cbe78c01eefe40

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't know if there a public-facing site for Microsoft checksums anymore, but the one for en_windows_xp_professional_with_service_pack_3_x86_cd_vl_x14-73974.iso is 66ac289ae27724c5ae17139227cbe78c01eefe40